In VSCode is there a way to focus on first editor in first group in one command without altering "last recently used editor"?
I want to focus on first editor in first group using a keybinding, then using another keybinding I want to switch the focus back onto the editor I was working on before. This previous editor might be in a different group.
Ideally I would like to achieve this using out-of-the-box commands that I can combined using keybindings and runCommands if needed. I would prefer not to have to develop my own VSCode extension to be able to do that.
Currently I have tried the following:

Focus to first editor in first group using a multi-commands keybinding:

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+j",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "name": "Focus On First Editor in First Group",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup",
        "workbench.action.firstEditorInGroup"
      ]
    }
  },


Switch focus back to previous editor using command workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor (assigned to a keybinding).

Issue
If I have multiple groups, this doesn't work as expected. The workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor command focus on an editor in the first group rather than the editor that was in focus when I triggered the first keybinding.
Why does this not work as expected?
The issue is that the shortcut described above has 2 steps:

focus on first editor group   <--- this actually focuses on an editor in first group
focus on first editor in this group

If I'm in group #2 when I execute this shortcut, then the command workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup is performed, it focuses on one of the editors in this group, therefore changing the "Previous Recently Used Editor". So when I later trigger workbench.action.openPreviousRecentlyUsedEditor, it doesn't go back to the editor that was in focus originally, but it goes back to this "intermediary" editor that has been focused by the command workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup.
